# Homestead not working after windows 10 latest update

Tags: laravel, homestead

Before updating windows 10 (november update) it all working perfectly using latest virtual box. after update everything is not working. I've tried reinstall the vagrant, virtual box no luck and i recheck the hosts file, it still the same where i left it before update.

All i getting when open using chrome is "Err connection reset".

Anyone having this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

Check the Oracle VirtualBox log for the vagrant machine, it would seem there are various issues being experienced, mine was related to VirtualBox network connection on Windows.